# VB6 True Transparent Background on User Control

Tags: user-controls, vb6, background, transparency, transparent

I am making a custom OCX where I would like the background to be true transparent. The OCX has 3 images, and a label. I would like the background to be transparent.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: A UserControl's BackStyle is trivially set to transparent.  It sounds as if you want it to be able to "cookie-cut" through the container (Form) to show the Desktop and windows underneath.

Answer (score 1):

yo can try using this API

```
Private Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal crkey As Long, ByVal bAlpha As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
```

search for it for more detail...